# SD Card fills up with GPS/*.txt files

Tags: sd-card, gps, samsung-galaxy-ace

My Galaxy ACE SD card fills up with .txt files in the GPS folder when the GPS is on. I often run out of space. This doesn't happen with my other Android phones.

How can I diagnose and fix this?

Comment: What information is found in these text files? How big is your sd card? Did you download an offline copy of the maps, or have you viewed and zoomed in all the way and explored a lot of places? These are the factors I can think of that could be causing this.

Comment: Also, it will be helpful if you (@Jake) can list any GPS related apps that has been installed by you or pre installed. To me, this appears some faulty app logs some details.

Comment: Since they are txt files, I would inspect them too to find the offender's name

Answer (score 4):

It's most probably a buggy 3rd party app (preinstalled by Samsung or by you).

To find the offender I'd install [Permissions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.FireFart.Permissions2) and narrow the problem down to apps with **precise GPS location** permissions.
If this list is huge you can also cross-check with running apps ([Task Killer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller) or [QuiteTaskmanager](http://code.google.com/p/quitetaskmanager/downloads/list), the latter lists more but is not available in Google Play).

If you're rooted you could also run 'lsof | grep sdcard' to see which processes have these gps/txt files open and subsequently delete the offending app, here's a sample output:

```
1|root@android:/ # lsof | grep sdcard
com.googl  2635    [...] /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.maps/[...]
com.fsck. 16308    [...] /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.fsck.k9/[...]
```