# Where did my 16gb of memory go?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-2, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I am not educated on Android enough to figure this out on my own. My problem began New Year's Eve with error messages saying device memory was full. My Galaxy S2 Skyrocket began to lag and wouldn't allow me to access photos or contacts. It would freeze. I'd remove the battery when it would get stuck restarting. I looked in "Storage" and found that the device's memory is only 1.97gb. Then I noticed that there was 11.26gb going to USB storage. Where did my memory go? I was told by a tech friend that I may have a "hidden partition." I appreciated a very basic, non-technical explanation on how to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where I could not figure out what was taking up my phone's storage.
I used an app called [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) to visualise the issue and find the folder causing the problem.

Comment: I use DiskUsage too whenever I want to know what files / folders are taking all the space, great little app.

Comment: The device only has 2gb. I know the 7 third-party apps and a few songs are using that 2gb. I can't even use the rest of the memory it's supposed to have. It's like I've been blocked from it or it was taken away.

Comment: Did DiskUsage only reveal that you had 2GB available?

Comment: Here's what I got: Storage Card- 30424MiB, Free Space- 28961MiB; Storage/sdcard0- 11525MiB, Free Space- 10410MiB.

Comment: App Storage is: Data- 2017MiB, Free Space- 980MiB, System Data- 69.8MiB

Answer (score 1):

When I was developing two years ago I altered the GPS settings on the device and they started outputting .txt files to the SD card. This made no sense to me and after looking into it if an application installed has this issue it will **persist** until the application is **removed**. I can not remember the folder location.

I want to say /sdcard/gps/* but here is a reference if this was the issue: [SD Card fills up with GPS/*.txt files](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26924/sd-card-fills-up-with-gps-txt-files)

Comment: I talked to Samsung. I ended up doing a factory data reset. Problem still persists. It's like I've been blocked from that remaining 14gb or it was taken away.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try changing to the install location to USB storage. It's already detecting it as USB storage, so maybe this would work.

By the way, have you got a memory card inserted?

Comment: Yeah. I'm putting all my pictures/videos on it.